# Maven multi-module project and unix/lf lineEnding issue

Tags: maven-2, maven-assembly-plugin

I am very new to Maven and running into a problem that I can't figure out. I have a multi-module project setup. In one of the sub-modules, I have some Unix bash scripts. In my assembly file, I want to build a zip file that contains all my Unix scripts with line ending of either "unix" or "lf". Every thing works as expected when I package my application at the sub-module level (scripts do have the right Unix line ending). However, when I package my application at the master project level, scripts don't end up in Unix line ending. Is there a solution for this problem ? Thanks.

Here is a sample snippet of my assembly file: (which is defined for one of my submodules at the submodule level)

```
<fileSet>
        <directory>src/main/scripts</directory>
        <outputDirectory>bin</outputDirectory>
        <lineEnding>unix</lineEnding>
        <fileMode>0755</fileMode>           
    </fileSet>
```

Comment: Impossible to answer without more details about your project structure, plugin version, a pom.xml, etc or, even better, a simplified sample project allowing to reproduce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're running into this bug: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MASSEMBLY-237.
Just force the assembly plugin version to 2.2-beta-3 and your problem should be solved.